# Setting up the directory management in Express Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I use **NodeJs**, **Express** and **Handlebars**.

My server file `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'index'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
  res.render('start'); // render the "start" template
});

app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 8888');
});
```

So when passing in the route `localhost:8888/start` there should be my `index.handlebars`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foo</title>
</head>

<link href="../../CSS/requirements.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>TEST - This is on all pages</p>

{{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

and the template to load (`start.handlebars`)

```
<script src="../Client/start.js"></script>

<p>Template 1 is active</p>
```

My directory structure

[image: Directory]

When running the server, my route is loading fine but the problem is, that the browser is not able to find the script and css files.

[image: Browser]

I checked my paths but I think they might be correct. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `static` folder in your `express` app. Add following middleware

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

right after

```
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Create a public folder at your root level and move your `Client` and `CSS` folder in that `public` folder.

Ref: [Link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)